# Creating an unordered list with image as the list item

Tags: html, css

I want to create an un-ordered list with an image as the 'bullet point'.

I have the following code:

html

```
<div class="a-checkpoint-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.a-checkpoint-list{
  list-style-image: url("images/Checkbox.svg");
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 12px;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

I would like for it to look like the following:

[image: Checkpoint-list]

at the center of the page. I cant seem to get it to look this way with my current css code. Any idea where I'm going wrong as I'm fairly new at this.

**Updated code**

css

```
.mc-checkpoint-list > ul{
list-style-image: url('../images/Checkbox.svg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
line-height: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
font-size:16px;
}

.a-checkpoint-list{
margin-left:40%;
}
```

img
[image: Test-description]

**Working Code**

css

```
.mc-checkpoint-list > ul li{
    background-image: url(../images/checkbox.svg);
    list-style-type:none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-size:17px;
    margin-top:20px;
```

}

Comment: you can try **pseudo css elements**  like after, before

Comment: @AdnanAkram I tried the following line but it still doesnt display the img i give. 

    .a-checkpoint-list > ul > li:before{
    content: url(images/Checkbox.svg);
    }

Comment: you probably need something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/pg0e10g3/ [click run to get the image loading] (don't use "text-align:center" and use some margin auto to center)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9qg2rfsw/1/      check this

Comment: what did you mean by this update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just simple:

```
ul {
    list-style-image: url('imagename.svg');
}
```

For you it should be like:

```css
.a-checkpoint-list > ul {
    list-style-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaaDU.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="a-checkpoint-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice @ketan. Superb.

Comment: Thanks @ketan. This got the image into my list. Is it possible to have the image aligned with the text?

Comment: @MichelleAshwini It is depend on image size. Decrease the image size. It will align with text

Comment: @AdnanAkram this is what OP wants

Comment: @ketan I still cant get the image to be inline with the text.

Comment: @MichelleAshwini Can you show your updated code. And upload image with it.

Comment: @MichelleAshwini you have use `list-style-image` instead of `background-image`. And also change `.mc-checkpoint-list > ul li{` instead of `.mc-checkpoint-list > ul{`

Comment: Thank you! thank you! @ketan finally got it. Will post my final code in a bit.

Comment: @MichelleAshwini. You welcome. glad to help. And don't forgot mark it as answer.

Comment: @ketan how can i add some spacing between the 'bullet' image and the text?

Comment: @MichelleAshwini increase `padding-left`

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.a-checkpoint-list{width:200px;margin:0 auto}

.a-checkpoint-list ul{
  list-style-image: url("download.jpg");
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 12px;
  font-size:16px;

  }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="a-checkpoint-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.a-checkpoint-list ul {
  list-style-image:url("images/Checkbox.svg");
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0px auto;
  font-size:16px;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```
<div class="a-checkpoint-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

may this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Check below code may help you.

```css
div.a-checkpoint-list ul {
  list-style-image: url("http://findicons.com/files/icons/1156/fugue/16/tick_circle_frame.png");
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-checkpoint-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>
        <li>Test 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the css as follows

```
 .a-checkpoint-list {
  padding-left: 12px;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  }
  ul {
    list-style-image: url('images/Checkbox.svg');
 }
```